# Where can I get the parameters specific to each time zone to use with win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation()?

Tags: python, winapi, timezone, ntp

Is there any way I could get the parameters specific to each time zone to use with the [`SetTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-settimezoneinformation) API call? The following is an example for the EST time zone.

```py
win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation((-600,u'Eastern Standard Time' (2000,4,1,3,0,0,0,0),0,u'Eastern Daylight Time',(2000,10,1,2,0,0,0,0),-60))
```

The documentation for [`win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__SetTimeZoneInformation_meth.html) has this information:

> ```py
> tuple = SetTimeZoneInformation(tzi)
> ```
>
> Sets the system time-zone information.
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `tzi` : tuple
> A tuple with the timezone info
>
> #### Comments
>
> The tuple is of form:
>
> #### Items
>
> [0] `int` : Bias
> [1] `string` : StandardName
> [2] `SYSTEMTIME tuple` : StandardDate
> [3] `int` : StandardBias
> [4] `string` : DaylightName
> [5] `SYSTEMTIME tuple` : DaylightDate
> [6] `int` : DaylightBias

When I tried [`win32api.GetTimeZoneInformation`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetTimeZoneInformation_meth.html) to find my local system's time zone information, I got the following values

> `(0, (-240, 'Arabian Standard Time', (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 'Arabian Daylight Time', (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 0))`

This is accurate, but it doesn't allow me to gather time zone information for a time zone other than the implied one for the calling thread. I wish to create a table for all time zones. Is there a way to get this information?

Comment: I'm not aware of an API that returns this list. .NET's [`GetSystemTimeZones`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getsystemtimezones) parses keys under the *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones* registry key to retrieve this information. I haven't yet looked at how C++' time zone support is implemented.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-enumdynamictimezoneinformation enums all **dynamic** timezones as stored in the registry. Also note the warning on the MSDN docs for SetTimeZoneInformation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-settimezoneinformation

Comment: Good information, @Remko. I knew it somehow had to be there. Unfortunately, those Vista+ APIs seemingly [aren't available](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html) through PyWin32.

Comment: Honestly, you're much better off making a shell execute call to `tzutil /s` - where you only have to pass the Windows ID of the desired time zone.